# Как из массива целых чисел найти все возможные комбинации (не только двух чисел, а и более, без повтора) дающие искомую сумму?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Есть массив, к примеру:

```
const arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 13, 31, 31, 44, 51, 81, 65, 63];
```

и искомая сумма, целое число, к примеру пусть будет:

```
const target = prompt("enter number", "52");
```

Как найти все возможные ряды (массивы) чисел из массива, которые дадут в сумме искомую сумму, не используя дважды одно число из массива?

Comment: Самый простой и медленный способ - перебор

Comment: Кто вам дает все эти задания? Проку с них особо нет и ответы уже есть в сети. https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.eedd0838-63b68246-455f84ef-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum,
https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-tasks/thread2973216.html

Comment: `не используя дважды одно число из массива` - стоит уточнить эту сентенцию ввиду наличия `2, 2, 2, ...` и т.п.

Comment: Т.е. массив можно уменьшить избавившись от дубликатов?

Comment: EzioMercer, не совсем, вікидівать из массива те числа, которые уже(если) использовались, дубликаты или нет

Answer (score -2):

https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-tasks/thread2973216.html Списал оттуда ,Списал оттуда ,признаюсь,но там написанно на python а вам нужно на javascript вот я и переписал на js)

лучше используй это конечно

```
Array.prototype.sum = function() {
    return (!this.length) ? 0 : this.slice(1).sum() +
        ((typeof this[0] == 'number') ? this[0] : 0);
};

function comb_sum(arr, cnt, s) {
    var n = arr.length
    res = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i < 2 ** n + 1; i++) {
        var tmp = new Array()
        var p = 1;
        for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i & p) {
                tmp.push(arr[j]);
            }
            p *= 2;
        }
        if (tmp.sum() == s & tmp.length == cnt) {
            console.log(tmp)
            res += 1;
        }


    }
}
```

доробатывай,иногда повторяются массивы к примеру

```
comb_sum([7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8], 3, 23)
```

Как использовать?

```
//первым принимается массив , вторым колво цифр , третьим сумму которую надо набрать данным количеством цифр
//massivChisel , количество слагаемых , сумма
  comb_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 1, 8)
  comb_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2, 8)
  comb_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 3, 8)
  comb_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 4, 8)
  comb_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 5, 8)
  .....
  //и т.д.
```

так же можно и по другому ,перебрав сразу все:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
for(var i = 1;i<=arr.length;i++){
 comb_sum(arr, i, 8)
}
```

Comment: И сюда притащили это... Если понимаете, что там делается, то доработайте без использования cnt

Comment: секундочку,сейчас отредачу

Comment: если вам не важно cnt то можно сделать от 1 до длинны массива :)